# CSS not working on Firefox/IE - file paths?

Tags: css

I've got a stylesheet that works fine on Chrome and Safari, but looks horrible on IE and Firefox, like it's failing to identify any of the code. I think it might be something to do with the file paths I've used on the url sections of background images etc, but I'm not sure how to fix it - any ideas? Code below, thanks in advance.

Example code:

```
h4#forensic{background-image:url('~/images/Layout/Headers/header-forensic.jpg');}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using '~' in the background-image url? Did you check if you respect the sensitive syntax?

And the first / means you give the path relative to your domain. Remove it to use the path relative to the css file.

Sebastien

Answer (score 0):

Try and remove the tilde `~` character and possibly the first slash.